access vba dlookup with dates
I'm trying to work and understand how to deal with dates in ms access vba and tables.
I have this variable:
Dim locking as Date
locking = Now

then I proceed and update some table from vba with the sample code:
query = " UPDATE table " & _
        " SET locktime = """ & locking & """ & _
        " WHERE recordID = 1"
        
db.Execute query, dbFailOnError

lockTime is a date field in the table definition.
if the update query is successfull and always is, I then need to retrieve in another portion of the code the locked ID and assign it to a variable :
lockedID = DLookup(recordID, "table", "lockTime = locking")

I don't understand how to deal with that datetime criteria, I've tried multiple quoting and using the # symbol to no avail
of course I get multiple type mismatch error
I believe I'm not handling properly both the initial 'query' syntax and the dlookup one

In both, use # delimiter and concatenate variable: "lockTime=#" & locking & "#". Or don't use variable: "lockTime=Now()". However, Now() includes time component. Maybe should use Date() instead.

Field to search in should be in quotes: DLookup("recordID", "table", "lockTime = #" & locking & "#")

I need the time component as the record locking part of the code needs it

Why does UPDATE have a static recordID parameter?

How a date variable is converted to string is dependent on your locale settings. To make sure it works, use Gustav's CSql() function when concatenating variables with SQL. It handles date/time and other variables.

As you will always come to the point that you have to deal with date and time in queries, you can create a small function which delivers the date/time as string which can be easily used in and SQL string or a dlookup:
    Public Function DateToSQL(ByVal dte_IN As Date) As String
   ' Converts a date/time to a SQL date/time
   '
   ' IN:  Date
   ' Out: String for direct use in SQL's
   '
   ' Example
   '   strReturnValue = DateToSQL(now())
   '   Returns: #02/17/2024#
    
   Dim strDateTmp     As String
   Dim strReturnValue As String
   
   On Error GoTo DateToSQL_ERROR
    
   strReturnValue = "ERROR"
   strDateTmp = "#" & _
                    Format(dte_IN, "MM") & "/" & _
                    Format(dte_IN, "DD") & "/" & _
                    Format(dte_IN, "YYYY") & " " & _
                    Format(dte_IN, "HH") & ":" & _
                    Format(dte_IN, "NN") & ":" & _
                    Format(dte_IN, "SS") & _
                "#"
    
   strReturnValue = strDateTmp
    
DateToSQL_EXIT:
   DateToSQL = strReturnValue
   Exit Function

DateToSQL_ERROR:
   Resume DateToSQL_EXIT
End Function


why would you go through all that if we have native vba functions?
I solved (for now at least) converting everything to US date/time (tried ISO to no avail tho):
Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss")
Format(whateverDateVariable, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss")
